# Navigating through a tree of graphql-data with react-navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

TL;DR: How do I subscribe* a component to a branch of a tree returned from graphql?

## The problem

I am working on an app where at the beginning we get a big tree of data from graphql and then you can navigate around in that tree on react-navigation screens and maybe mutate some data, which can affect the parents of that data in the tree.

My question is how to best handle the data in the app so that we don't need to make a new roundtrip to the server for every navigation step but still ensure that the data is synchronised.

### Current situation

The current horrible solution is to send around the data as navigation parameters, so anything would be better than that. We've had tons of bugs with unsynchronised data.

## Solutions

### Potential solution #1

One slightly better solution would be to put all the data in redux and fetch it from there, but that seems kind of redundant when we have Apollo and could still make keeping everything up to date difficult.

### Other potential solution

The third solution would be to put in separate queries for all the layers of the tree and possibly use `fetchPolicy='cache-only'`, but <strike>not every node in the tree has an id and</strike>** the schema doesn't have queries for the individual nodes. If it did, I think [cache-redirects](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-interaction/#cache-redirects-with-cacheredirects) could prevent the redundant fetches.

So I guess the real question is: Is there a good way to fetch the data from a specific part of a tree returned from graphql? I know about `client.readFragment`, but then the component won't automatically update whenever the cache changes. Maybe using a custom resolver?

### Yet another possibility

I guess another alternative would be to store the path in the component (e.g. as a navigation-param or in redux) and restructure the tree for fast access with reselect and then query for the whole tree in each component and extract the relevant part from that. This might be the easiest solution? But it feels like Apollo has already done this work, why do I need to do it again?

---

<sup>* Not subscribe as in a GraphQL subscription, just making sure it is kept in sync whenever the Apollo cache is updated, like `useQuery` does.</sup>

<sup>** That is not a problem, since is easy to mitigate with [custom identifiers](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-configuration/#custom-identifiers) in my case.</sup>

Comment: just don't use route based navigation? store path/app state in redux (or apollo local state) and render components conditionally ... id is required for normalized cache and shows tree dividing points ... sync with what? bugs on rereadings? will be more on storing whole tree and partial updates ... subscriptions required?

Comment: @xadm The screens that view the different parts of the tree are very conceptually different and can be reached in multiple ways and be navigated through in multiple ways, so I think react-navigation makes a lot of sense and removing it would be a major rewrite.

Comment: @xadm Id's can be generated from multiple fields so that's a minor problem. The sync problems I have is that updating data on one screen doesn't guarantee that it is updated on a different screen. No GraphQL `Subscription` is needed, just a subscription to updates in Apollo's cache, like you get from `useQuery`.

Comment: IMHO you need ids to have cache more granular/reactive ... can you isolate the problem with working [example] on codesandbox?

Comment: @xadm No, the ids are not relevant since I can use [custom identifiers](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-configuration/#custom-identifiers). But yes, an example would probably be helpful, but may take a while to set up, since there are many relevant parts to configure. For example, I don't know how to provide dummy graphql data or simulate a server for this?

Comment: :) I confirmed your notece about ids ... https://www.robinwieruch.de/graphql-server-mock-apollo-client ?